# Special array sorting on console with Delphi 7

Tags: arrays, sorting, delphi, delphi-7

My integer array is:

```
AR: array [0..5] of integer = (6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7);
```

Algorithm:

```
Take the first value of the AR array (6)
Find the first great value that comes after it (9)
Find out how ahead you are after yourself (4)
write this as the first value in the result array
....
Get the second value in the AR index (5)
The first great value after him (9)
Find out how ahead you are after yourself (3)
write 3 after 4 in our results series.
.
.
```

This process will be repeated for each array entry. If there is no larger than the values ​​that follow, `'0'` will be written. The last value must be `'0'`.

The expected output must be:

```
OutValue = 4-3-2-1-0-0
```

I don't have the codes that really work.

```
const
AR:array [0..5] of integer = (6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7)
var
S:Tstringlist;
output:string;
i,j,g,n:integer;
begin
S:=Tstringlist.create;
for i:=0 to 5 do
for j:=i+1 to 5 do begin
if AR[i] > AR[j] then begin
g:=0;
AR[i]:=AR[j];
AR[i]:=g;
S.add( inttostr(g));
end
else if AR[i] < AR[j] then
begin
g:=sizeof(maxintvalue(AR[i]));
AR[i]:=AR[j];
AR[i]:=g;
S.add( inttostr(g));
end;
end;
For i:=0 to 5 do
begin
//S.Sorted:=true;
output:=S.Text;
end;
S.free;
writeln(output);
readln;
end.
```

Thank You.

Comment: Show us the code that is not working.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 'Show us the code that is not working. '   > code edited

Comment: You still have not told what "is not working" means. Give sample data, error messages, expected result, actual result.

Comment: Are you sure that your expected `OutValue = 4-3-1-1-0-0` is correct? If I try to calculate the result manually following the same approach that you have shown for first two numbers in your array I come to end result of `4-3-2-1-0-0`

Comment: actual result > OutValue = 4-3-2-1-0-0 is correct .@SilverWarior thank you. However, I could not find a solution on how to do this. Another entry example AR :(1,2) >>> OutValue= 1-0 A hint would be good to find the location of the greatest value after the next number. Thank you

Comment: What would be expected result in case when input array is `6, 5, 9, 7, 8, 4`? Would it be `2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0` or `2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0`?

Comment: @SilverWarior values ​​you entered 6,5,9,7,8,4 >>> 2,1,0,1,0,0 
is true. Because the great value after 7 becomes 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly. The following approach (using a nested `for` loop) is a possible solution to your problem.

```
program SpecialArraySort;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure SortArray;
const
   aInput: array [0..5] of integer = (6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7);
var
   aOutput: array [0..5] of integer;
   i, j, value, offset: Integer;
begin
   // Generate output
   for i := 0 to 5 do begin
      value  := aInput[i];
      offset := 0;
      for j := i + 1 to 5 do begin
         if value < aInput[j] then begin
            value  := aInput[j];
            offset := j - i;
         end{if};
      end;
      aOutput[i] := offset;
   end;
   // Print output
   for i := 0 to 5 do begin
      Write(IntToStr(aOutput[i]) + ' ');
   end;
end;

begin
   SortArray;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Excellent.